# Running calculation of elapsed time between dates in GroupBy

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a df similar to:

```
id start_dt    end_dt
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-14
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-15
1  2021-01-13  2021-01-16
2  2021-02-01  2021-01-04
2  2021-02-01  2021-01-07
```

I am looking to create a third column "diff" which would represent the running difference in days grouped up by ID.  The calculation would take into account overlap of the start_dt and end_dt from the previous record in the GroupBy series.

Expected Output:

```
id start_dt    end_dt      diff
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-14  14
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-15  1
1  2021-01-13  2021-01-16  1
2  2021-02-01  2021-01-04  4
2  2021-02-01  2021-01-07  3
```

I had this coded and working in another language which I am now porting over to Python and I've been stuck on this.  Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Let's see the code you used

Comment: if you group by id than find the min start dt for the group and the max end dt for the group and the date difference between the min and max dates for the day count.   The result should be one row per group id.  I think your resulting output is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Python question but a Pandas one. You can use `groupby` and `apply` here, but you must make sure to save the original index:

```
def make_diff(dg):
"""
the tranformation function that builds a Series with the differences in days
and uses an 'index' column as index
"""
    prev = dg['end_dt'].shift()    # the end date of previous row
    # compute the actual start date
    start = np.where(prev.isna()|(prev<dg['start_dt']),
             dg['start_dt'], prev)
    # and returns the Series
    return (dg.set_index('index')['end_dt'] - start).rename('diff')

df['diff'] = df.reset_index().groupby('id').apply(make_diff).reset_index(level=0)['diff']
```

With your example dataframe, it gives as expected:

```
   id   start_dt     end_dt    diff
0   1 2021-01-01 2021-01-14 13 days
1   1 2021-01-01 2021-01-15  1 days
2   1 2021-01-13 2021-01-16  1 days
3   2 2021-02-01 2021-02-04  3 days
4   2 2021-02-01 2021-02-07  3 days
```

The only requirement is that rows are correctly ordered in each group.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my situation.  The only thing I ended up changing was converting 'diff' to a numeric value which can be utilized later in my program.

Comment: To add to level of complication, how I can use the busday_count() functionality to calculate the "diff" column in this instance?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We start by preparing the dataframe, for reproducibility (your dataframe is inconsistent as far as I can tell)

```
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime
data = StringIO(
"""
id start_dt    end_dt
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-14
1  2021-01-01  2021-01-15
1  2021-01-13  2021-01-16
2  2021-02-01  2021-02-04
2  2021-02-01  2021-02-07
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace = True)
df['start_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_dt'])
df['end_dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_dt'])
```

Next we converts dates to days, as offset to some arbitrary `base_date`

```
base_day = datetime(day = 1,month = 1,year = 2021) # does not really matter
df['start_day'] = (df['start_dt'] - base_day).dt.days
df['end_day'] = (df['end_dt'] - base_day).dt.days
```

next we

- find a rolling max of `end_day` up to the previous row, per group (hence `offset(-1)`)
- figure out `from_day`
- take the difference

```
df['max_end_day'] = df.groupby('id')['end_day'].rolling(window = 100, min_periods = 1).max().reset_index(drop=True).shift(1)
df['from_day'] = df[['start_day','max_end_day']].max(axis=1)
df['diff'] = df['end_day'] - df['from_day']
```

we get (with all the intermediate calculations for clarity)

```
      id  start_dt             end_dt                 start_day    end_day    max_end_day    from_day    diff
--  ----  -------------------  -------------------  -----------  ---------  -------------  ----------  ------
 0     1  2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-14 00:00:00            0         13            nan           0      13
 1     1  2021-01-01 00:00:00  2021-01-15 00:00:00            0         14             13          13       1
 2     1  2021-01-13 00:00:00  2021-01-16 00:00:00           12         15             14          14       1
 3     2  2021-02-01 00:00:00  2021-02-04 00:00:00           31         34             15          31       3
 4     2  2021-02-01 00:00:00  2021-02-07 00:00:00           31         37             34          34       3
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution as I tried it out and it did provide an accurate result

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by id then find the min for start_dt and max for end_dt then create a new column call diff which is the difference in days

```
id=[1,1,1,2,2]
start_dt =['2021-01-01','2021-01-01','2021-01-13','2021-02-01','2021-02-01']  
end_dt=['2021-01-14','2021-01-15','2021-01-16','2021-01-04','2021-01-07']


df=pd.DataFrame({'id':id,'start_dt':start_dt,'end_dt':end_dt})
df['start_dt']=df['start_dt'].astype(np.datetime64)
df['end_dt']=df['end_dt'].astype(np.datetime64)
print(df)
grouped=df.groupby('id').agg({'start_dt':'min','end_dt':'max'}).assign(diff=lambda row: (row['start_dt']-row['end_dt']).dt.days)
```

output:

```
  start_dt     end_dt  diff
id                            
1  2021-01-01 2021-01-16   -15
2  2021-02-01 2021-01-07    25
```

Comment: This isn't a bad option but the issue is that there can be a gap between the "start_dt" and the previous "complete_dt" of a group.  The min and max wouldn't account for this.  Thank you though.

Comment: is there a way to partition the date data with a numeric value so the grouping will work